# "Reg" function in VB6

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I am converting on an old piece of code and converting it from VB6 to C#. I came across the function.

```
!Cod_Item = Trim(Reg(objCodItem))
```

I searched the msdn documentation but could not find anything for "Reg" function. Can you explain what is the use of this function?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just defined somewhere else in your old piece of code?

Comment: It looks like a string array

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the full source code and as per the client it is a standard VB6 function. I just wanted to check here before going back to the client.

Comment: What happens when you position your cursor over `Reg` in the IDE and right-click and select "Definition"?

Comment: The code has been shared with me in a word file along with the enhancements that is needed in the existing functionality :)

Comment: Is it safe to assume that "Reg" is not a standard function in VB6 so that I can ask my client to find a little more about this function?

Comment: If could be a function written in VB6

Comment: `Reg()` is not a built-in VB6 function; its something created by the author of the code - either a function or an array/collection type variable.  You will need to ask the author.

Comment: Thanks Alex, Rob, Senshin and Plutonix. I will ask the concerned team to get the details.